# Perl & mod_fcgid- how can I be sure it's working?

Tags: perl, fastcgi, mod-fcgid

I have a couple Perl scripts I'm taking public soon, and I want to make sure they'll run under `mod_fcgid` in order to keep the server load as low as possible.  Previously, I've only ever run scripts that test FastCGI (ie, `while ( my $q = new CGI::Fast ) { $count++; echo $count;})` or taken advantage of larger Perl packages (like MovableType) that claim to run as FCGI as long as you set up Apache & FastCGI/`mod_fcgid` properly and change the file suffix to "`.fcgi`".

So, here's my question: do I need to do anything besides change the file suffix of my scripts, and if so, what?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to install FastCGI and configure your Apache to use it, but I assume you knew that. To test if your code is in fact running under FCGI instead of regular CGI, you can use the `IsFastCGI` method from the [FCGI](http://search.cpan.org/~skimo/FCGI-0.67/FCGI.PL) request object, which CGI::Fast uses under the hood.

```
use FCGI;

my $request = FCGI::Request();
if ( $request->IsFastCGI ) { 
    print "we're running under FastCGI!";
} else { 
    print "plain old boring CGI";
}
```